# Generate a random number that meets a given predicate

Tags: algorithm, random, f#

I would like to be able to generate random numbers that all meet a given predicate, for example only generate random numbers that are even or prime. Is there an algorithm to do this in a relatively efficient way? The way I have found to do this is to go brute-force:

```
let randIntSatisfy (randGenerator: System.Random) (satisfy: int -> bool) =
    // The maximum number of tries before returning `None`
    let maxTry = 100

    let rec inner i =
        function
        | num when satisfy num -> Some num
        | num when not (satisfy num) && (i < maxTry) -> inner (i + 1) (randGenerator.Next())
        | _ -> None

    inner 0 (randGenerator.Next())

let example =
    let randGen = new System.Random()

    seq { for _ = 0 to 10 do
              yield randIntSatisfy randGen (fun x -> x % 2 = 0) }
```

This code will not loop forever but will not guarantee to find a number that satisfies the given predicate (assuming such a number exists of course, if I ask for a negative number, then the function will return `None` all the time for example). Is there a way to do a little better than that?

PS: I've used F# here, but I'm not specifically asking for a language-specific answer.

Comment: Is there a limited range in which you want to find the number? If yes and the range is not to big, you could create a set of all numbers that satisfy your restriction and than randomly choose one of them.

Comment: Combinatorial Sampling is hard. I think collecting as much information as possible is necessary. The approach mentioned: enumeration + uniform selection is easy and correct = uniform (but won't do for big solution-spaces). Rejection-sampling is usually easy and correct = uniform (but is a las-vegas algo and quickly can lead to exponential-time usage). There are generic combinatoric sampling approaches in SAT and Constraint-Programming, but this is not easy (and also is a trade-off). And then there is the world of markov-chain samplers... But well... not my expertise. Heavy statistics stuff.

Comment: If uniformity isn't that important: just use a CP or SAT-solver and randomize the seed (and other settings) implying a very limited form of randomness (they will show problems when analyzed!). Those solver could also help doing the enumeration which is part of the approach mentioned above (when you got more jointly defined constraints).

Comment: @sascha I hadn't thought about SAT-solvers, it seems interesting to use here. I'll go and check out a way to use that.

Comment: @MrSmith42 If I need to generate a lot of numbers, then your approach seems to be the most efficient, thanks for the idea.

Comment: If the predicate is something like "an even number" (or more generally "a multiple of n"), or "a power of n", or similar, you don't even need to enumerate the possible values: just generate a random integer and compute the number you need. For instance to generate a multiple of 5 you multiply by 5 your random value. If the predicate is "a prime number" or "a Fibonacci number" of course things are more difficult

Comment: so you need to find a function that maps from a signed int to the target space you want. I don't think there's going to be a simple general solution, you don't just need to map, you also need to decide how you want the answers distributed, even 'even' numbers arent trivial, you want just evens representable by int32? or any even number?